# Customising pandas dataframe to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

i have a dataframe df as follows

```
A B C    
1 2 3   
a b c
```

I need to convert it to json as follows:

```
'{"data" :[  
{'type':'df',
 'column_name':'A',
'values':['1','a'] },  
{'type':'df',
 'column_name':'B',
'values':['2','b'] },  
{'type':'df',
 'column_name':'C',
'values':['3','c'] }
] }'
```

How can i do it easily ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html ?

Comment: Can you show your effort so far?

Comment: I achieved it using concatenation of strings, a typical approach where  you just combine strings according to your requirement. I wanted to know if there is any better way of doing it or an inbuilt function which i can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the dataframe and add the values to your own custom dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = defaultdict(list)

for column in df.columns:
    d['data'].append(
        {'type' : 'df',
        'column_name' : column,
        'values' : df[column].to_numpy() }
    )
```

---

```
print(dict(d))
out:
    {'data': [{'type': 'df',
   'column_name': 'A',
   'values': array(['1', 'a'], dtype=object)},
  {'type': 'df',
   'column_name': 'B',
   'values': array(['2', 'b'], dtype=object)},
  {'type': 'df',
   'column_name': 'C',
   'values': array(['3', 'c'], dtype=object)}]}
```